# Script optimisation to find duplicates filename in huge CSV

Tags: bash, awk, grep, uniq, optimization

I have several CSV file from 1MB to 6GB generated by `inotify` script with a list of events formatted as is:
`timestamp;fullpath;event;size`.

Those files are formatted like this :

```
timestamp;fullpath;event;size
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_OPEN;2324
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_ACCESS;2324
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE;2324
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/quad_list_14.json;IN_OPEN;2160
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/quad_list_14.json;IN_ACCESS;2160
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/quad_list_14.json;IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE;2160
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/masterbias_list.asc;IN_OPEN;70
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/masterbias_list.asc.1;IN_OPEN;80
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/masterbias_list.asc.2;IN_OPEN;70
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/otherfolder/quad_list_14.json;IN_OPEN;2160
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/otherfolder/quad_list_14.json;IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE;2160
```

My goal is to identify the file with the same name that appears in different folders.
In this example, the file `quad_list_14.json` appears in both `/home/workdir/otherfolder` and `/home/workdir/`.

My desired output is simple just the list of file that appears in more than one folder in  this case it would look to this:

```
quad_list_14.json
```

To do this I've written this small piece of code:

```
#this line cut the file to only get unique filepath
PATHLIST=$(cut -d';' -f 2 ${1} | sort -u)
FILENAMELIST=""

#this loop build a list of basename from the list of filepath
for path in ${PATHLIST}
do
    FILENAMELIST="$(basename "${path}")
${FILENAMELIST}"
done

#once the list is build, I simply find the duplicates with uniq -d as the list is already sorted
echo "${FILENAMELIST}" | sort | uniq -d
```

Don't use this code at home it's terrible, I should have replace this script with a onliner like this :

```
#this get all file path, sort them and only keep unique entry then
#remove the path to get the basename of the file 
#and finally sort and output duplicates entry.
cut -d';' -f 2 ${1} | sort -u |  grep -o '[^/]*$' | sort | uniq -d
```

My problem though remains and lot of file and the shortest takes 0.5 second but the longest takes 45 seconds on a SSD(and my production disk won't be as fast) to find duplicate filename in different folder.

I need to improve this code to make it more efficient. 
My only limitation is that I can't fully load the files in RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following AWK script should do the trick, without using too much memory:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = ";"
}

{
    idx = match($2, "/[^/]+$")
    if (idx > 0) {
        path = substr($2, 1, idx)
        name = substr($2, idx + 1)
        if (paths[name] && paths[name] != path && !output[name]) {
            print name
            output[name] = 1
        }
        paths[name] = path
    }
}
```

It extracts the path and name of each file, and stores the last path it’s seen for every name. If it had previously seen another path, it outputs the name, unless it’s already output it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I really need to learn awk looks awesomely effective

Comment: You made the most effective script.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with your code is that you're collecting all the pathnames in a variable and then looping over it to call `basename`.  This makes it slow.

The loop also runs over the unquoted variable expansion `${PATHLIST}`, which would be unwise if the pathnames contain spaces or shell globbing characters. In `bash` (or other shells that supports it), one would have used an array instead.

Suggestion:

```
$ sed -e '1d' -e 's/^[^;]*;//' -e 's/;.*//' file.csv | sort -u | sed 's#.*/##' | sort | uniq -d
quad_list_14.json
```

The first `sed` picks out the pathnames (and discards the header line).  This might also be written as `awk -F';' 'NR > 1 { print $2 }' file.csv`, or as `tail -n +2 file.csv | cut -d ';' -f 2`.

The `sort -u` gives us unique pathnames, and the following `sed` gives us the basenames.  The final `sort` with `uniq -d` at the end tells us which basenames are duplicated.

The last `sed 's#.*/##'` which gives you the basenames is reminiscent of the parameter expansion `${pathname##*/}` which is equivalent to `$( basename "$pathname" )`.  It just deletes everything up to and including the last `/` in the string.

The main difference from your code is that instead of the loop that calls `basename` multiple times, a single `sed` is used to produce the basenames from a list of pathnames.

---

Alternative for only looking at `IN_OPEN` entries:

```
sed -e '/;IN_OPEN;/!d' -e 's/^[^;]*;//' -e 's/;.*//' file.csv | sort -u | sed 's#.*/##' | sort | uniq -d
```

Comment: Grep seems to be a 20% faster: `grep -oP '^[^;]*;\K[^;]*' file.csv | sort -u | grep -oP '.*/\K.*' | sort | uniq -d`

Comment: @isaac Possibly. It would depend on what implementations of `grep` and `sed` one used. BSD `sed` is generally faster than GNU `sed`, and GNU `grep` may be faster than GNU `sed` too... I'm on a BSD system, so using GNU `grep` isn't something I'm "automatically" doing.

Comment: @Kusalananda see my answer after some testing ;-) thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both of you for your answers and thanks Isaac for the comments.
I've taken all your code and put them in a script `stephen.awk` `kusa.sh` and `isaac.sh` after that I've run a small benchmark like this:

```
for i in $(ls *.csv)
do
    script.sh $1
done
```

With the command `time` I compare them and here's the results:

**stephen.awk**

```
real    2m35,049s
user    2m26,278s
sys     0m8,495s
```

**stephen.awk**: updated with /IN_OPEN/ before the second block

```
real    0m35,749s
user    0m15,711s
sys     0m4,915s
```

**kusa.sh**

```
real    8m55,754s
user    8m48,924s
sys     0m21,307s
```

Update with filter on `IN_OPEN`:

```
real    0m37,463s
user    0m9,340s
sys     0m4,778s
```

*Side note:*
Though correct I had a lot of blank line outputed with `sed`, your script were the only one like that.

**isaac.sh**

```
grep -oP '^[^;]*;\K[^;]*' file.csv | sort -u | grep -oP '.*/\K.*' | sort | uniq -d
real    7m2,715s
user    6m56,009s
sys     0m18,385s
```

With filter on `IN_OPEN`:

```
real    0m32,785s
user    0m8,775s
sys     0m4,202s
```

**my script**

```
real    6m27,645s
user    6m13,742s
sys     0m20,570s
```

@Stephen you clearly win this one, with a very impressive time decrease by a 2.5 factor.

Though after thinking a bit more I came with another idea, what if I only look at OPEN file event it would reduce the complexity and you're not suppose to access a file or write it without opening it first, so I did that:

```
#see I add grep "IN_OPEN" to reduce complexity
PATHLIST=$(grep "IN_OPEN" "${1}" | cut -d';' -f 2 | sort -u)
FILENAMELIST=""
for path in ${PATHLIST}
do
    FILENAMELIST="$(basename "${path}")
${FILENAMELIST}"
done
echo "${FILENAMELIST}" | sort | uniq -d
```

With this only modification which gave me the same result I end up with this `time` value:

```
real    0m56,412s
user    0m27,439s
sys     0m9,928s
```

And I'm pretty sure there's plenty of other stuff I could do

Comment: Plug that grep into Stephen's and my solution too and you'll probably see an equivalent speed increase. Just don't do that loop with `basename`!

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarking! I’m curious how the AWK version improves if you change the second block to start with `/IN_OPEN/ {`...

Comment: Likewise for mine. I have added this restriction at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda what if I use an array instead ? @StephenKitt See updated result with the filtering. `awk` is definitely quicker.

Comment: I simply fail to see how looping over `basename` can even get close to being as fast as a single `sed` invocation. Our approaches are _identical_ in all other aspects (depending on what tool you use for the first step of the pipeline, but I gave a few alternatives).

Comment: I'll edit this answer but it seems your second onliner gives 38 seconds which is almost as good as awk script. I kind of see where the flaw is in my logic